# Logging in to Yahoo Messenger using their newly released API

Tags: jquery, json, rest, oauth, yahoo-messenger

Im trying to login to yahoo messenger using the newly released messenger api.I referred to http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch05s03.html .I signed up for the API and have got a Consumer Key and a Consumer Secret.My yahoo id is bob.m@yahoo.com(not the real one,just for the sake of example).To login i hit the following url from the browser:

```
https://login.yahoo.com/WSLogin/V1/get_auth_token?login=bob.m&passwd=<my_password>&oauth_consumer_key=<my_oauth_consumer_key>
```

I get the following response in the browser:

```
Error=MissingParameters
ErrorDescription=Sorry, try again with all the required parameters.
```

I even tried making a $.getJSON call to the url in code using jquery passing the above parameters but that didnt work too.
Any way to fix this?

Please help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

use ?**&** before login parameter like this
?&login=myusername&passwd=mypass&oauth_consumer_key=myconsumerker.
by the way, where do you live i ask becuse of this
http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch06s02.html#